# Backbone.js Collection not updating

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am new to `backbone.js`
I am adding rows dynamical in table(HTML), but when I print table data on save button it display empty data, my code is as follows

```
(function($){

Backbone.sync = function(method, model, success, error){
    success();
}

var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        srNo:1,
        name: ''
    }
});

var ListPerson = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person
});


var ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr', // name of tag to be created

    events: {

        'click span#spanDelete': 'remove'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'unrender', 'remove'); 

        this.model.bind('add', this.render);
        this.model.bind('remove', this.unrender);
    },
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).append("<td>"+this.model.get('srNo')+"</td><td><input  type='text'  id='txt1' value="+this.model.get('name')+"></td><td><span class='delete' id='spanDelete' style='cursor:pointer; color:red; font-family:sans-serif;'>[delete]</span></td>");
        return this; 
    },
    unrender: function(){
        $(this.el).remove();
    },
    remove: function(){
        this.model.destroy();
    }
});

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'), // attaches `this.el` to an existing element.
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addItem', 'appendItem'); 

        this.collection = new ListPerson();
        this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem); 

        this.counter = 0; 
        this.render();
    },
    events: {
        'click button#btnAdd': 'addItem',
        'click button#btnSave': 'saveData'
    },
    render: function(){
        var self = this;
        $(this.el).append("<button id='btnAdd'>Add list item</button>");
        $(this.el).append("<table border=1 id='dtl1'></table>");
         $(this.el).append("<button id='btnSave'>Save</button>");
        _(this.collection.models).each(function(person){ 
            self.appendItem(person);
        }, this);
    },
    addItem: function(){
        this.counter++;
        var person = new Person();
        person.set({
            srNo:  this.counter // modify item defaults
        });
        this.collection.add(person); 
    },
    appendItem: function(item){
        var itemView = new ItemView({
            model: item
        });
        $('table', this.el).append(itemView.render().el);
    },
    saveData: function(){
         var obj=this.collection.toJSON();
          var str_json = JSON.stringify(obj);
          alert(str_json);
    }
});
var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);
```

[image: This is my form]

[image: Outupt on Save button]

**Name is not display in output**

Comment: Don't `$(this.el)` when you already have [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-$el). Don't `$('table', this.el)` when you have [`this.$('table')`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar). Don't `_(this.collection.models).each` when you have [`this.collection.each`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods).

Answer (score 1):

From what you have posted, I do not see you setting `name` attribute of your Person model anywhere. Within your `addItem` method, I see you setting the `srNo` attribute but nothing is done to the name as far as I can see here.
Relevant part of your code below,

```
var person = new Person();
 person.set({
    srNo:  this.counter // modify item defaults
 });
```

So you need set your `name` attribute like you are setting the `srNo` attribute

Comment: How can i set value in Person Model that is entered in text field  ? please tell me, i dont know how to set.

Comment: If you have a text input element say `name`. Then in you `addItem` method, you can do something like                                                                   
               `var nameVal = $("#name").val();
     console.log('Name:'+nameVal); //just to verify that you have the name
     person.set({name:nameVal});`

Comment: I have tried this code but it is not working, when i click first time on 'Add list Item' button  $("#name").val() get undefined value.

Comment: Did you add an `input box` in your html whose id is `name`? If you have not added this html element, `undefined` would be the value you would get.

Comment: Yes i have html input tag and i also have given id to this, in above example i have given id as 'txt1' and i tried var nameVal = $("#txt1").val(); person.set({name:nameVal}); but it is not working.

Comment: Did you log it just to make sure you have the value, something like console.log('Name:'+nameVal);

Comment: Yes i have printed using alert(nameVal),have you tried this code? and is it working with you?

Comment: Yes I did. Though this is pretty basic, I wouldn't post something without trying. What does it show you in the log for the `Name` value?

Comment: This clearly means that the name value is not being passed to your variable and hence will not get set correctly for Backbone Model as well. I am assuming you have some text in your input box. Can you try to grab the name value without jquery and see if that helps, something like `var nameVal = document.getElementById('txt1').value;` and then again log it to see what this variable is set to

Comment: When i click on button second time, i got value that i inserted into first row of table.

Answer (score 1):

I got one tricky solution for this,  i trap change event of inputtext in event block of **ItemView**(In above example) as   events: {'click span#spanDelete': 'remove',**'change input#name':'textChange'** }, and in textChange method i write following code         
 `textChange: function(e){

           this.model.set('name',$(e.currentTarget).val());
      
  }`
When i print collection value in alert i got all names inserted in inputtext.